# What does a "monadic structure" and "element of a structure" precisely mean in the context of arbitrary Monad?

Tags: haskell, monads, algebra, category-theory, io-monad

Reading through the documentation of Control.Monad I found such description of [mapM](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mapM):

> Map each element of a structure to a monadic action, evaluate these actions from left to right, and collect the results

I'm interested, what does “element of a structure” mean for an arbitrary monad? E.g, `State` or `IO` monad? What a structure?
I know what `mapM` function does and interesting more in the *semantics* of this particular words in the description of `mapM`. Does this "structure" somehow connected with the notion of "algebraic structure"?

> Structure is a set with one or more finitary operations defined on it that satisfies a list of axioms.

If so then what are the elements of this structure (carrier set) as I asked for e.g. IO monad? In general?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Element of a structure" means exactly nothing for an arbitrary monad, because it doesn't reference the monad. The `mapM` you're referring to is a member of the `Traversable` typeclass, and the structure it refers to is the `Traversable`. A `Traversable` is a data structure that can be mapped over, such as a list or a tree. "Element of a structure" refers to the list's elements.

Answer (score 4):

The 'structure' here is the instance of the `Traversable` class (i.e. the type constructor `t` in the signature of `mapM`).